# Export command line argument and set it as constant for a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, export

I am new to node.js.

I want to get an argv from my command line when I am going to start my server and then I want to set it as a constant for a module.

For example I want to define my log file path from commandline:

```
node server --logFilePath="LOGPATH";
```

And want to use as like below:

in db.js, rest.js like below:

```
function writeIntoLog(message, LOGPATH){
        //
}
```

What I have tried :

in server.js I am exporting the argv like below:

```
module.exports.argv = argv;
```

And in db.js including it by var server = require('server.js');

```
console.log(server.argv)
```

But if I call it inside server start block like below:

```
server.listen(argv, function() {
        console.log(argv);
        console.log("started server");
  });
```

It prints the passed arguments. It seems sever.listen is called at last.

I am clueless how I can get the passed argiments and set it as Constant for different operation(ex. log path)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. the command line arguments are an array of strings called `process.argv`. This starts with node, then your script, then the additional arguments.
2. To parse the actual options and flags, typically people will use a helper module. Search on npmjs.org to find one you like or implement your own.
3. To store the value, just set it into `module.exports.logPath = valueFromCommandLine`;